# "$MAKEOPTS" ignored, why?

Tags: environment-variables, makefile, .profile

I have defined

```
export MAKEOPTS="-j4"
```

in my ~/.profile file.

But when I do a compilation with make, this option is ignored.
I've consulted the GNU Make manual but it says nothing about this variable. Is it standard or only it works in certain distros?

Comment: Where have you seen this being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export MAKE="make -j4"
```

This will help invoking child `make` processes, but I'm afraid this wouldn't help with direct invocations, like just `make all`. Though a shell alias may help with the direct ones, so:

```
MAKEFLAGS="-j4"
export MAKE="make $MAKEFLAGS"
alias make="make $MAKEFLAGS"
```

Comment: Thanks. "MAKEFLAGS" do de job.  

But if I set 'export MAKE="make $MAKEFLAGS"' when I do a make, it shows this warnings: "warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode."

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest, before today I'd never seen `MAKEOPTS`.

`MAKEFLAGS` I know of but after some research, `MAKEOPTS` appears to be Gentoo- (and its children) specific.

And if it's not in the manual, it can hardly be considered standard by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: `strings /usr/bin/make | grep MAKEFLAGS` shows some usage in my Ubuntu distro.

Comment: @ulidtko Please re-read. I wasn't doubting the existence of `MAKEFLAGS`. The question is about `MAKEOPTS` -- which can't be found in `make`.

Comment: you're right, I have confused `MAKEOPTS` in your answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
MAKEOPTS="-j4"
```

to `/etc/make.conf` (create it if it doesn't already exist).